# Angular material component looks different when added to a blank angular app than it does on the example

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I added the Angular Material component "Toolbar" to my project and it doesn't look the same as it does in the example even though, as far as I can tell, all the styles are the same.

This is what it looks like in the example from the project website.

[image]

For debugging purposes, I created a blank angular app and added Angular Material and just the toolbar component and it looks like it does in my actual project which is like this. Debugging Angular app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9eywwc)

[image]

This is the example html and css that works how I want it to:
I have copied it to stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xebnxaepbbp)

index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
  <toolbar-basic-example>loading</toolbar-basic-example>
</div>
<span class="version-info">Current build: 10.2.0</span>
```

component html

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>My App</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
    <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

style.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

component css

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Here is my debugging angular app that I want to look the same as the example and is copied to stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9eywwc)

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <div class="mat-app-background basic-container">    
  <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

component html

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>My App</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
    <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

component scss

```
.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Why doesn't my angular app look like the example from the Angular Material website and how can I correct it so that it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not importing `MatButtonModule` so the `mat-icon-button` directive does nothing.

Here's an updated app.module.ts with the import

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,

    // you were missing this
    MatButtonModule,

    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9eywwc-xsjtpo?file=src/app/app.module.ts